# How do I get SQL database users & roles into my MVC EF project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio

I was able to create the SQL database tables using "schema compare" in visual studio.  I added the login & user to the database directly using T-SQL, and also used T-SQL to add the user to datareader & datawriter roles.

Now, when I do a "schema compare" in visual studio using my project as the source, it wants to delete the user and roles from the database.  How do I add these to the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you are using the new Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT) project (.sqlproj) or the older 2010 SQL Database Project (.dbproj).

If you are using the new SSDT project - then you just add the objects into the project:

- Create a file for your new Login
- Create a file for your new DB User
- Create a file called YourDatabaseName.rolememberships.sql

That file will have code in it like:

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datareader', @membername = N'NewDBUser';
```

And you will need a Permissions.sql file.  In there you will grant the Login connect rights like this:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO [NewLogin] AS [dbo];
```

---

If however you are using the old database project you will need to create a new project in your solution called a Server project.  It looks very much like your database project, except it is of the master database.

You do similar things in this new server project as I outlined above and in your original database project you will need to add the server project as a reference.

---

A caveat to this whole process.  You will want to add the Login with the SID value so that you don't end up with orphaned user scenarios when you try and put a backup of your database on some other server.

I have used the process outlined in [this MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992) to get the SID in the first place and then if you refer to the BOL section about [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) you will see what the syntax should be for creating your login file.